# What's the formal name of this network configuration?

Tags: networking

I'm researching a network inside another that can't access the internet but can be accessed by the internet. I've seen terms like cascading and heard something like a "v" configuration but neither gives good search results. If you shield one network inside another, what's that called? The intent is to prevent unwanted communication going online but enabling a look inside that shielded network for updates, upgrades and monitoring.

Comment: how about `intranet`? .... a network that is behind a firewall .......

Answer (score 2):

This type of setup is similar to how some military networks are set up that work at different levels of security clearance.

e.g. a top secret network linked to a unclassified network.

The way these are set up are with what is known as a [network diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidirectional_network). This is a machine that can only send information in one direction. Which would be the unclassified network can send data to the top secret network but not the other way round.

These diodes are normally built using a fibre optic ethernet card with only 1 fibre. Normally the cards would have a 2 fibres, one for transmit and one for receive. The transmit fibre from the unclass network is linked to the receive port on the machine on the top secret network. (you normally need to splice the transmit fibre back into the receive port on the unclass side as well to make things work nicely.

The unclass side can then send UDP packets to the top secret network, but nothing can get out the other way.

The other similar situation is what is called a [bastion host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host). This is a machine that is on both networks, but does not allow routing between the networks.

Any data has to be copied to the bastion machine first and then onward in either direction.